# How to Run a SaltStack Script as a Non-root User on a Salt Master Host?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to execute a Python script using SaltStack's `LocalClient` on a Salt Master host, but encountering issues when running it as a non-root user. The script works fine under the root user. My non-root user's Python environment is set up with pyenv and Salt was installed via pip in this virtual environment. The Salt installation on the host machine was done using yum under the root user. Here's the script:

```py
import salt.client

def run_shell_command(cmd: str, tgt: str = "*"):
    client = salt.client.LocalClient()
    res = client.cmd(tgt=tgt, fun='cmd.run', arg=[cmd])
    print(res)
    return res
```

When I run this script as a non-root user, I get the following error: "The salt master could not be contacted. Is master running?" How can I configure my setup to allow a non-root user to execute this script successfully?

How can I configure my setup to allow a non-root user to execute this script successfully?

Comment: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/eauth/access_control.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did the test according to the description in the document. It did work in the command line, but it still didn't work in the python script. Later I saw such a description in the official document. I think this should is the reason for failure.```Note

For Tiamat-bundled Salt distribution, you need to use the bundled Python runtime as the system Python won't be able to access Salt internals.

To execute scripts via bundled Python runtime, either run the script with /path/to/salt python script.py or use #!/path/to/salt python shebang```